# List refresh after delete in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angularjs.I have created one order List and have delete button in every row. My delete function is working fine,what i need to do to refresh the list after delete success.
this below is my sample code

```
$scope.deleteFunc = function (id) {
    var deleteOrder = $resource('/api/orders/:id', { id: id });
    deleteOrder.delete();
    Order = $resource("/api/orders")
    $scope.Order = Order.query();
    };
})
```

Please suggest the proper way how to refresh the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular resource requests are asynchronous. So when you do `deleteOrder.delete()`, the request need time to execute.

So when you do `Order.query()`, the request of the delete may still be in progress. So your server just give your order again in your list.

You must refresh the list after the end of the delete request.

```
$scope.deleteFunc = function (id) {
    var deleteOrder = $resource('/api/orders/:id', { id: id });
    deleteOrder.delete(function() {
        // This function will be called at the end of the delete
        Order = $resource("/api/orders")
        $scope.Order = Order.query();
    });
};
```

Comment: can i use $scope,Order instead of $scope.list that u have mention.Because i tried two line after the comments.its not refreshing

Comment: Oh maybe i didn't understand something. I edit my response.

Comment: Thanks alot.its working,how can i add success callback after the delete function, so that i can show some alert message to user,that order is deleted successfully.

Comment: You can put it after the `Order.query()`.

Comment: Its really helpful.Thanks alot.